# How to get CATextLayer’s wrapping count in order to calculate height

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, word-wrap, catextlayer

I am adding text incrementally to a wrapping `CATextLayer` in a `UIScrollView`. Each time I add text, I need to add height to the textLayer and to the scrollView’s `contentSize`, and adjust the scrollView’s `contentOffset`.

(The user should be able to use the scrollView to review previous text, but when new text is added, I want to scroll down to it programmatically.)

UIKit’s `sizeWithFont:` will treat the entire string as though it is on one line, so in order to calculate the height, I need to multiple the size.height returned by the number of lines, as produced by the textLayer’s wrapping.

Trouble is, if I access the string through the textLayer, it won’t contain any extra ‘\n’ or ‘\r’ characters to account for the wrapping.

Surely there is some way I can get the wrapping info? Perhaps dervied from superclass `CALayer` somehow? Otherwise I’m stuck calculating my own line breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `CATextLayer` internally uses Core Text for layout, so you could do the same and use `CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints` to calculate an appropriate height for an attributed string with a given width.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ended up forgoing CATextLayer's wrapping behavior and doing my own line breaks -- which I would have had to do in this case anyway because I'm using different fonts for different lines, causing variations in their size.

But I don't understand why CATextLayer doesn't allow access to what its wrapping functions are doing -- either adding the line breaks to the string property itself, which we could then access, or simply providing a "lineCount" read-only accessor.

Comment: I would assume that for attributed strings, `CATextLayer` uses Core Text for layout, so you could use `CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints` to determine the layer's height.

Comment: *That's* the answer. Thanks. If you post it as such, I'll mark it as the accepted answer. I think I saw something about framesetter at some point but it didn't click. So now it's back to the drawing board...

Comment: I've posted my comment as an answer now.