# CATextLayer + NSAttributtedString + CTParagraphStyleRef

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation, core-text, catextlayer

I want to have some text with a custom line-spacing, so I wrote an attribute string with `CTParagraphStyleAttributte` and pass it to my `CATextLayer`:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
CTFontRef ctFont = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)font.fontName,
                                        font.pointSize, NULL);
CGColorRef cgColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
CGFloat leading = 25.0;
CTTextAlignment alignment = kCTRightTextAlignment; // just for test purposes
const CTParagraphStyleSetting styleSettings[] = {
    {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierLineSpacingAdjustment, sizeof(CGFloat), &leading},
    {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierAlignment, sizeof(CTTextAlignment), &alignment}
};
CTParagraphStyleRef paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(styleSettings, 2));
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            (id)ctFont, (id)kCTFontAttributeName,
                            (id)cgColor, (id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName,
                            (id)paragraphStyle, (id)kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                            nil];
CFRelease(ctFont);
CFRelease(paragraphStyle);

NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] 
                                                 initWithString:string
                                                     attributes:attributes];
_textLayer.string = attrStr;
[attrStr release];
```

But the line height is not changing. I think I am missing something here but I don't know what.

I've tried with `kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierLineSpacingAdjustment` and `kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierLineSpacing` but either of them don't seem to work (?). I tried also to set the alignment using `kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierAlignment` (I know `CATextLayer` has a property for that) just to test `kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName` is indeed working and it didn't.

I've noticed that even if I pass some crazy values (for example: `CTParagraphStyleCreate(styleSettings, -555);`) which leads me to ask myself: Does `CATextLayer` support paragraph attributes? If so, what am I missing here?

Comment: A) The count arg 2 really should be typed as a CFIndex. But since that's just long integer type specifically defined for expansion, I doubt it's really the problem. B) I've been able to get CATextLayer to pick up a tab stop via a paragraphStyle, so it must support some of those attributes -- but others, first line and head indent, had no effect, at least not in iOS 4.3. (I hope someone has the answer, because leading seems important to textLayer functionality.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your code, putting the NSAttributedString in a CATextLayer, and it ignored the formatting, as you said.

Then I tried drawing the exact same attributed string to a UIView `drawRect` method using `CTFrameDraw`, and it obeyed all your formatting.  I can only assume that CATextLayer ignores the majority of its formatting.  The [CATextLayer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATextLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) has a number of warnings about what it does in the interests of efficiency.

If you really need to draw to a `CALayer`, not a `UIView`, you may be able to create your own CALayer subclass or delegate and do the drawing there.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    //
    // Build attrStr as before.
    //

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect bounds = [self bounds];

    // Text ends up drawn inverted, so we have to reverse it.
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(ctx, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
    CGContextTranslateCTM( ctx, bounds.origin.x, bounds.origin.y+bounds.size.height );
    CGContextScaleCTM( ctx, 1, -1 );

    // Build a rectangle for drawing in.
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, bounds);

    // Create the frame and draw it into the graphics context
    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef) attrStr);
    CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), path, NULL);
    CFRelease(framesetter);
    CFRelease(path);

    // Finally do the drawing.
    CTFrameDraw(frame, ctx);
    CFRelease(frame);          
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dondragmer ;) This is the proof that CATextLayer does not support all attributes in the NSAttributedString.