# Drawing an NSAttributedString in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to draw an `NSAttributedString` in a rect, just like I would do with a normal string: `[normalString drawInRect:rect];` but I can't figure out how. I don't want any `UILabel` subclasses since I'm implementing a fast scrolling `UITableView` with no views, so it needs to be drawn. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Tasks/DrawingAttrStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000163-CJBGBIBJ) shows that drawing is only available on Mac.

Is drawing an `NSAttributedString` not possible on iOS?

Comment: Is [`CATextLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATextLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) not adequate?

Comment: Wouldn't this involve adding more views? I'd have to add the layer as a sublayer right?

Comment: @SedateAlien: `CATextLayer` is good, and may be suitable for this particular tast.  However, it doesn't obey all the formatting that can be contained in `NSAttributedString`.  See [CATextLayer + NSAttributtedString + CTParagraphStyleRef](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10071198/1318452).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [Core Text](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html) to draw attributed strings on iOS.

The basic procedure would be to create a `CTFramesetter` from the string and a rectangular `CGPath` (or any other shape you may want), then create the frame using `CTFramesetterCreateFrame` and draw it with `CTFrameDraw`.